# Visual C++ Command line App: Why am I getting Error C1069: cannot read compiler command line on release build only?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I am investigating why my application, which works in debug mode, throws the error

> Error C1069: cannot read compiler command line

This happens when I try to build the same application in Release mode. I'm working on a VS2013, Visual C++ Command Line Application.

Some similar problems on here suggest that there are issues with the TMP/TEMP files that the app is trying to access, however I assume that is not the issue since it's only complaining in release mode.

### Update

I'm not sure why this happened; I am trying again, both release and debug mode failed with the same error. When that happened, I had to assumed the error was with VS2013 and how it interprets file paths to TMP and TEMP. When fixing the file paths, it runs in both release and debug mode.

I wouldn't call this an answer, but if anyone has the same problem, fixing TEMP/TMP file paths by pointing to a directory without spaces in it...

Comment: This is not your application throwing an Error, but the build system complaining that it can not read the command line to build your program.  You need to turn on verbose build output and either understand it and fix the problem. Or post the relevant parts of it here (for us to look at).

Comment: Thank you for the quick comment, I will take a more thorough look.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2829760/overview-of-visual-studio-2013-updates